# Handling failed API response in fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, promise

In my application, I have a simple fetch for retrieving a list of users which sends over an authentication token to an API

```
fetch("/users", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    token: this.props.getUser().token
  })
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(users => this.setState({ users }))
  .catch(err => {
     console.error(err);
   });
```

However, the API may return a 401 error if the token is expired.
How do I handle it properly in the fetch so that the state is only set when the response is succesful?

Comment: you'd check the returned status in `.then(res => res.json())` instead of blindly returning `res.json()`

Comment: `res` inside your callback in the first `.then` should have probably a key named `status`. That's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cleaner way to handle success/error of a fetch response would be to use the `Response#ok` readonly property

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok

```js
fetch('/users').then((response) => {
  if (response.ok) {
    return response.json();
  }
  throw response;
}).then((users) => {
  this.setState({
    users
  });
}).catch((error) => {
  // whatever
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`res` inside callback function in your first `.then` function contains a key called `status` which holds the request status code.

```js
const url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/s41un';

fetch(url).then((res) => {
  console.log('status code:', res.status); // heres the response status code
  
  if (res.status === 200) {
    return res.json();   // request successful (status code 200)
  }
  
  return Promise.reject(new Error('token expired!')); // status code different than 200
  
}).then((response) => console.log(response));
```